# Chrome Extension: How do I use declarativeNetRequest to bypass the Content Security Policy

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, javascript-injection

I'm making an extension that injects a user provided script into the current website. I've gotten that part done (with the help of [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom)). Only problem is that on some websites, it doesn't work. It throws this error in the console: `Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'`. I have been trying to fix this using declarativeNetRequest, however it's not working.

rule1.json

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "priority": 1,
        "action": {
            "type": "modifyHeaders",
            "responseHeaders": [
                {
                    "header": "content-security-policy",
                    "operation": "remove"
                }
            ]
        },
        "condition": {
            "urlFilter": "*://*/*",
            "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"]
        }
    }
]
```

manifest.json

```json
{
    ...
    "permissions": ["scripting", "activeTab", "declarativeNetRequest"],
    ...
    "declarative_net_request": {
        "rule_resources": [
            {
                "id": "ruleset_1",
                "enabled": true,
                "path": "/rules/rule1.json"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Javascript

```js
let button = document.getElementById("run");
button.addEventListener("click", async () => {
    let input = document.getElementById("script");
    let script = input.value;
    await execInPage(script);
});
async function execInPage(code) {
    const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true });
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: tab.id },
        func: (code) => {
            const el = document.createElement("script");
            el.textContent = code;
            document.head.appendChild(el);
        },
        args: [code],
        world: "MAIN",
    });
}
```

I am using manifest v3.
The extension has not been published yet. I am using developer mode for now.

Comment: Your code works for me on github so you either don't have `"<all_urls>"` in `"host_permissions"` or another extension is interfering or it's a bug in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

rule_remove_csp.json

```
[
  {
    "id": 11,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
      "type": "modifyHeaders",
      "responseHeaders": [
        {
          "header": "X-Frame-Options",
          "operation": "remove"
        },
        {
          "header": "Content-Security-Policy",
          "operation": "remove"
        }
      ]
    },
    "condition": {
      "resourceTypes": [
        "main_frame"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: I was using `"condition": {}` and using `"condition": {"resourceTypes": ["main_frame"]}` fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't seem to work on websites that use the  element to set CSP.
Anyone has another solution?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Did you publish it on Chrome Web Store? I was wondering if Google accepted the code because MV3 doesn't allow to use any remotely hosted code.
[Remotely hosted code restrictions](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv3-migration/#remotely-hosted-code)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33310781)